# Selectively printing values from a python dictionary

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have have a huge graph consisting of well over 100000 keys so efficiency is a huge issue. I am going through every keys' value, and for every value, I want it to be a key in another dictionary, with the values being the remaining values... E.g...

```
graph = {'foobar': ['1', '2', '3']}
result = {'1' : ['2', '3'], '2' : ['1', '3'], '3' : ['1', '2']}  #in no particular order
```

Here is my code at the moment...

```
for i in heroDict.values():
    for j in i:
        if graph.has_key(j):
            tempDict = copy.deepcopy(i)
            tempDict.remove(j)
            heroList = tempDict
            graph[j] += heroList
        else:
            tempDict = copy.deepcopy(i)
            tempDict.remove(j)
            heroList = tempDict
            graph[j] = heroList
return graph
```

'heroDict' is a dictionary similar to the example except very very large.

The problem I am having is that my code is running very slowly because of the deepcopy() I am performing. so for the foobar example for example, I get '1' as a key. I copy ['1', '2', '3'] into a temporary dict so the changes to it wont affect my final dictionary that i return. Then I remove the key from the ['1', '2', '3'] and assign the key '1' to it. So I'm left with {'1' : ['2', '3']} which is what I want but its taking too long because its iterating 100000+ times.

My final question is, can I improve this in any way so it runs faster?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If I understand, you are looking at 100000 list of 99999 elements. 10Gigaobject will need a lot of RAM

Comment: Do you really need to build the second `dict` in memory ? It seems that it would be easier and not much less efficient to compute the values when you need them. What do you use it for ?

Comment: Building the second dict is just the way i've implemented it. It's whats making it slow. I can't think of another way to get the same result im getting now, but faster.

Comment: can you name the variables in your example the same as in your code ? it is not clear what graph is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permutations is included in `itertools`.

A typical use in your example is :

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> values = graph['foobar']
>>> result = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in permutations(values)}
>>> print result
{'1': ('3', '2'), '2': ('3', '1'), '3': ('2', '1')}
```

Works with any number of values in foobar. Permutations is a generator, so you may call one item at a time instead of generating the whole dict at once.

Not sure how fast that would be, though.

Comment: I will try it now and get back to you, thank you for the answer